# How to find the new and returning and existing customer in one month

Tags: sql-server-2012

This is my code

```
select 
    case when date = 'first_time_purchase' then 1 else 0 end as new_customer,
    case when date = 'first_time_purchase' then 0 else 1 end as returning_customer,
    min(date) over (partition by customer_id by customer) as first_time_purchase
 from  table_name
 where date between  '01-APR-2022' and '30-apr-2022'
```

Note - no of row is more than 1 billion

new who purchase first-time,
Returning who purchase more than one time,
Existing customer who earlier purchased,

| customer id | order_ date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | '01-Apr-2022' |
| 4 | '02-Apr-2022' |

I want  output as

```
| new customer | returning customer| existing customer| d
```

Comment: Can you explain more 
when date = 'first_time_purchase' then 1 else 0 end as new_customer
the case when date = 'first_time_purchase' then 0 else 1 end as returning_customer
Because both conditions same. How can I differentiate

Comment: I am little bit confused why this code is not working .

Comment: If anyone have suggestion regarding my code and logic. Most welcome

Comment: Please, help me . I am new on this platform